# Set gets emptied in a recursive function in Python

Tags: python, recursion

For an assignment I have to make a function that goes through a dictionary of people and finds those who are younger than the specified parameter. The dictionary is written in a way that each "person" has other people attached to them, which are their descendants, which can also have descendants etc. I need to make the programme work so that it goes through all of the descendants of a specified person and returns those who are younger than `n`. The problem is that I define a `set()` at the beginning of the function, and even though it gets filled afterwards, the value returned by the function is still `set()` because of its recursive nature. How do I fix this?

```
def funct(name, n):
    younger = set()
    for child in people[name]:
        if age[child] < n:
            younger.add(child)
        funct(child, n)
    return younger
```

and here's the data:

```
people = {
    "Adam": ["Matjaž", "Cilka", "Daniel", "Erik"],
    "Aleksander": [],
    "Alenka": [],
    "Barbara": [],
    "Cilka": [],
    "Daniel": ["Elizabeta", "Hans"],
    "Erik": [],
    "Elizabeta": ["Ludvik", "Jurij", "Barbara", "Herman", "Mihael"],
    "Franc": [],
    "Herman": ["Margareta"],
    "Hans": [],
    "Jožef": ["Alenka", "Aleksander", "Petra"],
    "Jurij": ["Franc", "Jožef"],
    "Ludvik": [],
    "Margareta": [],
    "Matjaž": ["Viljem"],
    "Mihael": [],
    "Petra": [],
    "Tadeja": [],
    "Viljem": ["Tadeja"],
}

age = {
    "Adam": 111, "Matjaž": 90, "Cilka": 88, "Daniel": 85, "Erik": 83,
    "Viljem": 58, "Tadeja": 20, "Elizabeta": 68, "Hans": 64, "Ludvik": 50,
    "Jurij": 49, "Barbara": 45, "Herman": 39, "Mihael": 32, "Franc": 30,
    "Jožef": 29, "Margareta": 3, "Alenka": 9, "Aleksander": 5, "Petra": 7}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to pass the `set` around explicitly, creating it when not supplied (i.e. on the initial call):

```
def funct(name, n, younger=None):
    if younger is None:
        younger = set()
    for child in people[name]:
        if age[child] < n:
            younger.add(child)
        funct(child, n, younger)
    return younger
```

As to why I set the default `younger=None`, see ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761).

I would also suggest *not* accessing `people` and `age` within the function by scope alone; make them explicit parameters.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without adding parameters to the function (The instructions for the assignment say: write the function funct(name, n),...)

Comment: @x4nga another option would be to explicitly roll the `set` returned by the recursive call (which you *don't currently assign*) into `younger`.

Answer (score 0):

Have `younger` hold the names of all descendants that meet the age requirement, not just the immediate children that meet the age requirement.

```
def funct(name, n):
    younger = set()
    for child in people[name]:
        if age[child] < n:
            younger.add(child)
        younger.update(funct(child, n))  # Changed line
    return younger
```